# When I'm initializing new Object it has already _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I didn't find information about it in google. I'm using nodejs, express, mongoose. I'm trying initializing new Object

```
var User = require("../modules/user/model/user");

var user = new User();
console.log(obj);
```

And console show me

```
{ _id: 587b9a34b03ab515e1cf01b9 }
```

I didn't save this object! Someone can say me is't normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal. Mongoose defines a new ObjectId for _id when you instantiate a document. This is useful at times when you want the _id of the document to be saved into a document in another collection which holds a ref to the instantiated document.

If it was not pre-defined then you have to save the document and read it back to know the _id of the document for saving it in to another collection.